# How to draw equidistant dashes using DashPathEffect

Tags: android, geometry

At the moment I’m using DashPathEffect with hardcoded intervals to draw a circle as next:

```
float[] intervals = new float[]{ 3, 18 };
DashPathEffect path = new DashPathEffect(intervals, 0); 
paint.setPathEffect(path);
… … … …
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
```

But this produces a non-equidistant dash where the circle starts and ends, as shown in the image below:

[image]

I can of course adjust it manually, but this would only work for one specific device density, and produce again the same problem in a different display density.
What would the formula to calculate equidistant dashes?

Comment: Which radius did you choose for the circle in the picture?

Comment: Currently the radius is 52dp. Using DPs to allow correct scaling in different densities.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need *n* dashes plus *n* gaps to have the same total length as the circumference of the circle. The below code assumes you've correctly determined both the `center` point and the `radius` you want to use.

```
double circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
float dashPlusGapSize = (float) (circumference / NUM_DASHES);
intervals[0] = dashPlusGapSize * DASH_PORTION;
intervals[1] = dashPlusGapSize * GAP_PORTION;

DashPathEffect effect = new DashPathEffect(intervals, 0);
paint.setPathEffect(effect);

canvas.drawCircle(center, center, radius, paint);
```

For instance, I've used `NUM_DASHES = 20`, `DASH_PORTION = 0.75f`, and `GAP_PORTION = 0.25f`, and I see:

[image]

You can use different values for these constants to change how many dashes you chop the cirlce into, or how big the dash/gap are relative to each other (as long as `DASH_PORTION` + `GAP_PORTION` adds up to `1`).

Comment: If you are using `PathEffect.dashPathEffect`, the radius should be in PX since intervals are PX.
`val circumference = with(LocalDensity.current) { radius.dp.toPx() * Math.PI * 2 }`

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a different figure you can use this method to measure your custom path length:

```
    val measure = PathMeasure(path, false)
    val length = measure.getLength()
```